# How to connect to a remote PostgreSQL server using pgAdmin and Unix Domain Socket over SSH tunneling

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to connect to a remote PostgreSQL server from my Windows machine using pgAdmin.

Can I connect to the server **using unix domain socket over SSH tunneling**?
The PostgreSQL server and the tunneling SSH server are running on the same machine.

In [pgAdmin documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.21/server_dialog.html), the Host name/address field of the Server Dialog is explained as:

> Specify the IP address of the server host, or the fully qualified domain name in the Host name/address field. **If you provide a unix domain socket, the directory name must begin with a “/”**.

so, I specified `/var/run/postgresql` in that field to use a unix domain socket, but the following error message appears:

```
Unable to connect to server:

server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

This is the server machine's log:

```
systemd[1]: Started Session 28 of user ***.
sshd[630]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user *** by (uid=0)
sshd[634]: error: connect_to /var/run/postgresql: unknown host (Name or service not known)
sshd[630]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ***
```

Of course, I can connect to the PostgreSQL server using a unix domain socket on the server machine.
The following `psql` command works.

```
$ psql -h /var/run/postgresql -U *** -d ***
```

Comment: You could use socat to bridge tcp to unix domain socket. So ssh with local port forwarding -> socat -> unix domain. Of course you need access to a shell on the server

Comment: @Pat I guess from a security stand of view, that might not be a great idea.
BTW, having the same issues on my current setup. Shigure, did you maybe figure this out already?